# Keyboard does not hide on window load

Tags: android, titanium, appcelerator, android-softkeyboard

I am using Titanium for android app development. Can anyone suggest how to hide keyboard on window load. I have tried `textfield.blur()`, `SOFT_KEYBOARD_HIDE_ON_FOCUS`... but it's still not hiding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with `Ti.UI.Android.hideSoftKeyboard()`

Answer (score 2):

try doing this in your onload, it will ensure the window is loaded and the text field rendered

```
setTimeout( function() {
    textfield. blur();
}, 200);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```